# Android Studio - Attribute android... is not allowed here - AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, attributes

I have been searching for the solution to this problem for a couple days. None of the answers I've found so far, have worked. Here's what I've tried:

1. Invalidating Cache and Restart
2. Sync project with gradle files
3. Close manifest and reopen
4. Change Sdk min and target levels
5. Rebuild project

None of that is working. After creating a new project using 'Basic Activity', 'Test6' for a name, 'Kotlin' for a language and a minimum SDK of API 28.. here's my AndroidManifest.xml file:
[AndroidManifest.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFeR3.jpg)

Each of the android:... entries, that are red, has the error given in the title.
The ...".MainActivity" entry has this error: Unresolved class 'MainActivity'

[Project structure plus MainActivity.kt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IERDE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need the xmlns defined to enable android: prefixes.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

For the activity name, you can use absolute name which means to add the package name e.g.,

```
mydomain.mypackage.MainActivity
```

If you want to use short name, your activity must be in the same package defined in the manifest file:

```
package="mydomain.mypackage"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
Looking at the picture I sent I have the xmlns defined correctly according to what you mentioned. The activity name... should that be, in the case of my example:
     `com.fordummieslikeme.test6.MainActivity` ?

That seems to be what you're saying, but doesn't work.

I believe the package is also correct in my case, right?

Thanks again.